# Ordering elementtype by custom field throws an error

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

In my plugin, when I go to the elementtype index page with the search bar and the dropdown for ordering by certain fields, when I choose a field which has been added through the fieldLayout, the response throws an error.

The problem in the query is in the `ORDER BY` clause. Specifically: `ORDER BY 'field:22'`.

How would I go about resolving this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to debug without seeing any of the relevant plugin code or the error message.

Comment: @BradBell - I found out that Craft Commerce doesn't allow sorting by custom fields, so I assumed it's not available "out of the box" and opted to allow sorting only by the element's own fields.